# Are eval() and spl_autoload_register / __autoload() only ways to create classes on runtime?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm writing a devel module (so please no "you shouldn't do it" comments).

My framework already uses __autoload(), so I cannot use it. I would like to refrain from using eval() and writing temporary files, too. Is there any way to creaet child classes on the fly?

Like, I can create methods using __call() and properties using __get() / __set(), but I would really prefer to dynamically create a subclass. Like, TableUsers as a subclass of Table when working with 'users' table, to make sure properties in class match fields in table.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right solution? Smells like the XY problem here

Comment: If what you are talking about is monkey patching an existing object instance with functionality at runtime then I have had some luck creating a stream wrapper that returns a closure on include.

Comment: @DamienPirsy I'm not sure what's XY problem is. All I want is to be able to generate classes on the fly as needed, and then dump ones I actually needed to files for future adjustment.

Comment: @Orangepill I updated the end of my question a bit.

Comment: I mean, are you sure you need to create classes on the fly (problem Y), and not having another easier approach to your original problem (problem X)?

Comment: So you are looking for a db scaffolding tool. Something that can create table classes from the definition of a table that exists in the DB but in runtime?

Comment: @DamienPirsy What I want is a class generator with fast prototyping. I can live without generating classes on the fly, but it will make my tool less usable for me and will require me to alter code that uses it to actually use static classes in late development stage and production.

Comment: @Orangepill - I wrote small scaffolding tool for my needs. Now I want to add some convenience to the ways it can be used. Now it can create class files all right. But not the classes themselves at runtime, so changing database definitions is painful as it requires me to regenerate classes each time, or use generic classes and then rewrite code to use generated ones.

Comment: Show a class definition and method signatures of your scaffolding tool... that mixed with the stream wrapper approach may give you some love.

Comment: Zend Framework also has a low fat table class (only have to specify the table name and primary key) and you can get a lot of mileage out of it but I think your are probably already reasonably committed down a different path. But it might be work looking at to draw some inspiration from.

Comment: @orangepill - It'll be on my drupal.org sandbox when we'll make it stable enough. But now all I want is to create a class on the fly. All methods I'm using now in my real working classes are __call() and __callStatic() anyway, so I don't need anything from the child classes that are to be created, except the proper name and parent. If it cannot be done, so be it. And I don't see how stream wrapper should have anything to do with it, when I'm in a Drupal environment and I don't interface database directly anyway.

Comment: @Orangepill - Drupal is not on Zend. Next version will include parts of Symfony, but not the scaffolding ones (I already asked in issue queue as a support request). That's why I'm doing my best to live without it. I can interface with tables all right, I'd just want a class for given table to have a name corresponding to that table. Will look at Zend, if it's doing it.

Comment: Stream wrapper makes it where you can say `include 'table.creator://tablenaem/tableclassname';` and get a class definition as though it existed in a real file :)

Comment: I will post an answer so you can see if it will work for you.

Comment: @Orangepill - Yep, from that side it looks OK, but I still can't just use `$users = new TableUsers();`. Anyway, that's half the way from where I am now to where I would like to be. Thank you.

Comment: To enable that you would have to include this in your __autoload strategy as a fall back. Only thing is for this you should tread very lightly as it does open you for arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 1):

For this implementation I will start out with a targeted usage:

```
 include "table.creator:///user_table/TableUsers/id";
 $ut = new TableUsers();
```

**NOTE** This should **NEVER** be used for production code but it is useful for prototyping.

First off define a stream wrapper:

```
class TableMaker_StreamWrapper {

    protected $_pos = 0;
    protected $_data;
    protected $_stat;

    /**
     * Opens the script file and converts markup.
     */
    public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        // break path into table name, class name and primary key
        $parts = parse_url($path);
        $dir = $parts["path"];
        list($garbage, $tableName, $className, $primaryKey) = explode("/", $dir, 4);


        $this->_data = '<?php class '.$className.' extends MyBaseClass {'.
        '  protected $primaryKey = "'.$primaryKey.'";'.
        '}';
        return true;
    }


    public function url_stat()
    {
        return $this->_stat;
    }

    public function stream_read($count)
    {
        $ret = substr($this->_data, $this->_pos, $count);
        $this->_pos += strlen($ret);
        return $ret;
    }


    public function stream_tell()
    {
        return $this->_pos;
    }


    public function stream_eof()
    {
        return $this->_pos >= strlen($this->_data);
    }


    public function stream_stat()
    {
        return $this->_stat;
    }


    public function stream_seek($offset, $whence)
    {
        switch ($whence) {
            case SEEK_SET:
                if ($offset < strlen($this->_data) && $offset >= 0) {
                $this->_pos = $offset;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            case SEEK_CUR:
                if ($offset >= 0) {
                    $this->_pos += $offset;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            case SEEK_END:
                if (strlen($this->_data) + $offset >= 0) {
                    $this->_pos = strlen($this->_data) + $offset;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then within our code we have to register the stream wrapper like so.

```
stream_register_wrapper("table.creator", "TableMaker_StreamWrapper");
```

Then when you want to create a table wrapper around a class you have but to ...

```
include("table.creator:///my_table/MyTableClass/id");
```

and then you will be able to make `new MyTableClass` to your hearts content.

if you want additional syntactic sugar you can create a little factory function like this.

```
function get_table($tableName, $className, $pk= "id"){
     if (!class_exists($className)){
          require("table.creator":///".$tableName."/".$className."/".$pk);
     }
     return new $className();
}
```

Then you can just say.

```
$table = get_table("users", "UserTable");
```

Hope this helps